# Multiple Popup Menus

Tags: android, popupmenu

I want to use popup menu for two(2) buttons. The way I am achieving it right now is by making two separate xml files popup_menu1.xml and popup_menu2.xml which are inflated for each button, button1 and button2 respectively.
Popup-menu-1 has two(2) menu items and popup-menu-2 has four(4) menu items.
The pics are added for more clarification.

popup_menu1.xml has two menu-items, a seperate xml-file
popup_menu2.xml has four menu-items, a separate xml-file

each file is inflated for individual buttons.

**My Question is:** Can I use(inflate) only one(1) xml-file, instead of two separate xml-files, for two(2) buttons and showing two(2) different popup_menus?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

P.S: I wanted to add pictures for more clarity, but as a new member they are not allowing me to do it.

Code Added:
popup_menu1: File1

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu001">
  <group android:id="@+id/group_popupmenu">
      <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
          android:title="Today's Date"/>
      <item android:id="@+id/menu2"
          android:title="Custom Date"/>
  </group>
</menu>
```

popup_menu2: File2

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu002">
  <group android:id="@+id/group_popupmenu">
      <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
          android:title="Last Seven (07) Days"/>
      <item android:id="@+id/menu2"
          android:title="Today"/>
      <item android:id="@+id/menu003"
          android:title="Yesterday"/>
      <item android:id="@+id/menu4"
          android:title="Last Twenty Eight (28) Days"/>
  </group>
</menu>
```

Edit version 1:
Code In Activity Class:

```
// add a click listener to the first button
startDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu (CampaignDetailsActivity.this, view);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_menu_01, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu1:
    // some code here
    case R.id.menu2:
    // some code here   
        }
    return true;
    });
 popup.show();
 }
});

// add a click listener to the end date button
endDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View button) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu (TestAdlikelyButtonsAndMenuActivity.this, button);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.menu1:
                    // some code here
                    case R.id.menu2:
                    // some code here
                    case R.id.menu003:
                    // some code here
                    case R.id.menu4:
                    // some code here
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        popup.show();
    }
});
```

Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Workaround for the pics is to post your pics on an external website and then provide link to them.

Comment: you can post your code instead of pics

Comment: [link] (http://www.flickr.com/photos/80180394@N03/)
The pics are added, can you guide me about the solution.

Comment: @KMI: Should i share the code of xml files or activity?

Comment: @Ahmad Bilal::ya you can share java code also . i can get some idea

Comment: @silent: thanks for adding screen shots

Comment: @alextsc: why have u removed "android" from title?

Comment: Yes, you can inflate the same XML file multiple times to create multiple instances, but since you want them to have different content, it's not clear why you want to do that.  It looks like things already work the way you want them to, other than the strange idea that you shouldn't have two separate XML files for separate menus.

Comment: @AhmadBilal It's duplicate information *(you already have an android tag)* and it's pretty anoying when you browse the android question list. It looks like "Android - Question 1", "Android - Question 2", "Android | Question 3" and so on. Basically it just slows down parsing of the question list without any benefit. Tags should only be included in the [title if they fit organically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title).

Comment: @DarshanComputing: yes it might be strange. I just wanted to see if there is an option to achieve it or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can inflate a single XML file multiple times, but in the example you gave, you're doing it right by having two XML files.  After inflating, but before calling `PopupMenu.show()`, you can use one of the variants of [Menu.add()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to add items to the `Menu` (the one returned by `PopupMenu.getMenu()`).